# Sens de « tabouler »

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, verbes, france

*La Petite Fadette*, George Sand

> Aussi le lendemain, les bessons voyant qu'on ne les taboulait point, et que l'on comptait que la raison leur viendrait, se trouvèrent-ils plus effrayés de la volonté paternelle qu'ils ne l'eussent été par menaces et châtiments.

Que signifie le verbe « tabouler » ?. Il n'est pas dans le TLFi. Le Web reste muet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

J'ai trouvé une entrée dans [Le Drouviot](http://drouviot.net/dictionnaire/29-dictionnaire/22454-tabouler) :

> tabouler : Secouer

> Terme du vieux français, encore employé localement (Berry) , selon M.F. Azéma.

La citation est d'ailleurs ce même extrait de Sand.

---

J'ai également trouvé [cette source](https://www.lejsl.com/edition-montceau/2014/11/01/a-dire-vrai) (en français moderne) qui donne le sens de :

> proprement « cogner », « frapper ».

Comment: Belle trouvaille !

Comment: J'avais bien cru comprendre qu'il s'agissait d'un emploi au sens figuré.

Answer (score 1):

Il s'agit d'un mot du moyen français qui a survécu dans le parler de certaines régions, y compris le Berry (où se passe le roman), et qui signifie « frapper » ou  « faire du bruit », ou encore « secouer », « basculer ».

Selon [Du Cange](http://ducange.enc.sorbonne.fr/TABOLLARE):

[image]

D'après le *Grammaire et dictionnaire du patois bourbonnais* (1904) ce mot est spécifiquement berrichon :

[image]